Unable to deny SSH from other ips
Currently I am unable to deny ssh from other IPs, I am using hostinger Ubuntu VPS, have added restriction on the firewall. to allow IP from my IP and few others, but deny all others. This is not working, i am still able to get the SSH done from all the IPs.
Based on the recommendation hostinger support i followed these commands:
sudo ufw allow from 191.1.2.3 to any port 22
sudo ufw allow from 38.1.2.3 to any port 22
sudo ufw allow from 103.1.2.3 to any port 22
sudo ufw deny 22

This command is also not working, its allowing from other ips as well. I have a VPN setup and changed to other regions and it works well with other IPs as well.
Edit:
after running sudo ufw status output:
22                         ALLOW       191.1.2.3            
22                         DENY        Anywhere         
22 (v6)                    DENY        Anywhere (v6)  


What does sudo ufw status say?

`22                         ALLOW       191.1.2.3
22                         DENY        Anywhere`
it doesn't deny those connections, i can ssh from any ip.

I just did that, thanks

Thanks, are you sure what you posted is the full output? On my system sudo ufw status prints the firewall's status along with a header etc, is that all you get as an output?
